# Creating a Quote form in Django

Tags: python, html, django, rest

i am creating a django powered website. Specifically, a courier website. I need to create an application that serves as a quoting app. The user will type in the dimensions of the package into a form and after submitting the form, a price/quote will be returned , based on the dimensions inputted.

I have done this so far 
(views.py)

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from quote.forms import QuoteForm

    def quoting(request):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            form = QuoteForm()
        else:
            form = QuoteForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                Length = form.cleaned_data['Length']
                Breadth = form.cleaned_data['Breadth']
                Height = form.cleaned_data['Height']

                return redirect('thanks')
        return render(request, "quote/quote.html", {'form': form})
```

(forms.py)

```
from django import forms

class QuoteForm(forms.Form):

    Length = forms.Integer()
    Breadth = forms.Integer()
    Height= forms.Integer()
```

(quote.html)

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <div class="form-actions">
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Then i am aware i am lacking an html that would display the answer. I am not sure how to do this.

The price is determined by:

price= Shipping weight X distance
shipping weight= (length X breadth X height) / 5000

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You have redirected to a 'thanks' page after the input is received. You should not have to return anything at this point.

After you have the input of length, breadth and height. You can calculate the price by doing: (Length * Breadth * Height )/ 5000.

This can be stored into a variable 'total_price'. Then, add 'total_price' to your context when rendering.

Finally, in the HTML, you can add a Django template tag like

```
{% if total_price %}
   {{ total_price }}
{{ else }}
   {{ form }}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i have attempted it again, but am stuck here- see below

Answer (score 0):

When i submit the form it returns to just the form with my inputs

(views.py)

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from quote.forms import QuoteForm


def quoting(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = QuoteForm()
    else:
        form = QuoteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Length = form.cleaned_data['Length']
            Breadth = form.cleaned_data['Breadth']
            Height = form.cleaned_data['Height']
            totalprice=((Length*Breadth*Height)/5000)
    return render(request, "quote/quote.html", {'form': form})

def answer(request):
    return render(request,"quote/out.html")
```

(quote.html)

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<div class="form-actions">
<button type="submit" action='/quote/out.html/'>Send</button>
</div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

(out.html)

```
   {% extends "shop/base.html" %}
   {% block content %}
   {% if totalprice %}
   {{ totalprice }}
      {{ else }}
      {{form}}
{% endblock %}
```

(forms.py)

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):

    Length = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
    Breadth = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
    Height = forms.IntegerField()
```

(urls.py ( the app))

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
        url(r'^quoting/$',
            'quote.views.quoting',
            name='quoting'
            ),
        url(r'^answer/$',
            'quote.views.answer',
            name='answer'
            )
```